# How many wires have to be used?

Tags: 8051, databus

If there is needed to select a unit  of 32 Kbytes, one of 8 Kbytes,one of 8 bytes and two units of 2bytes.How many wires of address bus,data bus have to be used?

Comment: can somebody help please??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about programming.  See the [Help/on-topic].

Comment: What is your bus interface? Dallas one-wire needs only one data wire, even with multiple devices on the bus.

Comment: I suspect that this is about the address decoding required for the devices with the sizes specified in the question. If so it belongs in the Electrical Engineering forum and not here.